# In JMeter, Getting Error The SHA256 hash of the request body does not match the hash of the route"

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to script an API, in which I am providing the SHA256 HASH value of Body Data in the URL. However, I am getting an error '{"HashValidation":["The SHA256 hash of the request body does not match the hash of the route"]}'.

I have tried the API in Insomnia (similar to Postman), which is getting executed successfully. Does anyone ever encountered such an issue, do we need to pass the body in some other way in JMeter [Jmeter Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doRiQ.png)?[Jmeter response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh4a5.png)

Comment: are you sure this error throwing from jmeter ??

Comment: Yes, added the screenshot in the post.

Comment: Are you add headers to jmeter ? Like Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 0):

Either it's a bug in the application you're testing or it's an issue with your JMeter script.

You can calculate the SHA-256 hex of the request body using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) cpde like:

```
vars.put('sha256', org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()))
```

once done just replace the hard-coded checksum with `${sha256}` in the request path and the request should be successful given there are no issues with your application